# Distorted characters for JP & Ko in Struts 2 Form

Tags: java, unicode, localization, struts2, cjk

I'm using a Struts 2 app with Tomcat 6 server using JDK 1.7. We support more than 15 languages. I've a form which sends an email, with 2 issues:

1. When I type any Japanese or Korean characters in the form and submit it, the email body contains all ????????
2. I have a captcha on the form page. If I enter an invalid captcha for Japanese or Korean and click submit, it comes back to the same page, retaining username, email, etc. However, the retained characters are corrupted and do not remain in the same language in which they're entered. However, this happens only for Japanese and Korean.

I have this line in my JSP at the very top of the page:

```
 <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
```

Also, `server.xml` has a connector element which specifies URIEncoding="UTF-8"

These 2 issues are not present in other languages. Can any one tell me what am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoding problem seems to happen after you submit the form, in the code that prepares the email and sends it. Does your email program allow you to look at the raw data of the email? What's the (declared) encoding of the email? Can you have your email app choose an encoding? (And in which case make sure that UTF-8 is selected)?